# How display number in kibana pie graph

Tags: pie-chart, kibana, kibana-4

I have to create some dashboard on kibana and it's OK but I don't have the same rendering in kibana3 and 4.
It's filter split

**Kibana3**

[image: kibana3 I see percentage and number]

**Kibana4**
[image: Kibana4: no number]

I checked the option but still ...
Thanks for your help and have a nice day !

Comment: I do not think you can do this in Kibana 4.

Comment: Thanks Yuvraj, I don't think either ;( but I still have hope :) because it's really useful to get all number in a glance.

Comment: You should raise a discussion or issue in the forum @github.

Comment: Thanks Yuvraj for your idea, I will :)

Comment: And ... Done : https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6041

Comment: An older one: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2284

Answer (score 1):

We have a discussion in the github kibana issues section here: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2284. And I have posted a workable solution.

You might do it in this way. PS. I am using Kibana 4.5.4

[solution code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYeNP.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Answering with links is not a good one.  Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline there to provide quality answer.